# How to fetch a NSArray name from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

This is how I set or create my NSDictionary object:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefault setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[userDefault synchronize];
```

And, here I fetch and store into a local NSDictionary:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dictLanguage = [userDefault objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[userDefault synchronize];
```

Here I want to check whether it is @"ar" or @"en" in a same method:

```
if ([[[dictLanguage objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] isEqualToString:@"ar"]]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL, API_PRODUCT_MAIN_AR];
}
else if ([[dictLanguage objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL, API_PRODUCT_MAIN_EN];
}
```

Comment: You can't store an array and get back a dictionary. `dictLanguage` will be an `NSArray` containing an `NSString`. You will get an exception when you try and treat it as a dictionary. Also the calls to `synchronize` are unnecessary, especiallly on a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **userDefault** structure is like as shown below:

```
 {
        "AppleLanguages" : [
                            "ar"
                            ]
    }
```

So, your dictionary has *AppleLanguages* as **key** with an *array of values* as **Value**. when you access this key you get an Array not dictionary.

So, Instead of

```
NSDictionary *dictLanguage = [userDefault objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Use

```
NSArray *arrLanguage = [userDefault objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

and your If condition should be

```
if ([arrLanguage[0] isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL, API_PRODUCT_MAIN_AR];
}
else if ([arrLanguage[0] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL, API_PRODUCT_MAIN_EN];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you stored an NSArray , then you must read it as NSArray not NSDictionary also use this code to check current language

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrLang = [userDefault objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

if ([arrLang[0] isEqualToString:@"ar"]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL,    API_PRODUCT_MAIN_AR];
}
else if ([arrLang[0] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
    strCategoryUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_URL, API_PRODUCT_MAIN_EN];
}
```